# Create missing fields when converting from JSON

Tags: typescript

If I have a class such as:

```
export interface Results {
  xrf: any;
  ftir: any;
  level: any;
}

export class myClass{
  Results: Results;
  remark: string;
}
```

and a JSON object like:

```
{
  "Results": {
    "xrf" : "xrfresult",
    "level": "21"
  },
  "remark" : "Test 1"
}
```

If I parse the object using `let obj: myClass= JSON.parse(jsonobj)` The object is missing the field `ftir`. Is there any way to automatically create missing fields from a JSON object that does not have all the fields of a typescript class?

Answer (score 0):

Not all properties of an interface may be required. Some exist under certain conditions or may not be there at all. These optional properties are popular when creating patterns like “option bags” where you pass an object to a function that only has a couple of properties filled in.

Interfaces with optional properties are written similar to other interfaces, with each optional property denoted by a ? at the end of the property name in the declaration.

In your ftir is optional as input object doesn't have this property. if you try to access ftir after object assignment you will get undefined.

```
export interface Results {
  xrf?: any;
  ftir?: any;
  level?: any;
}

export class myClass{
  Results: Results;
  remark: string;
}


export class HomePage {
  results : Results;
  jsonObj : myClass;
  jsonString : any;
  ftir : any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.jsonObj={
  "Results": {
    "xrf" : "xrfresult",
    "level": "21"
  },
  "remark" : "Test 1"
}

this.ftir=this.jsonObj.Results.ftir
  this.jsonString=JSON.stringify(this.jsonObj);
  console.log(this.ftir);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there's no built-in way to do this. JSON operates on plain objects. Your type annotation has no impact at runtime, all types being erased, and is only allowed because `JSON.parse` doesn't return a specific type, it returns `any`.

It is an exceedingly bad idea to use an annotation of a class type on a reference to a deserialized value.

While you could theoretically implement functionality that instantiated your classes, you would need to do so manually at each call site or change the behavior of the global `JSON` object. The latter approach is really not viable because you will break your dependencies, and the former approach is a maintenance nightmare that introduces extraordinary complexity as soon as you inevitably introduce nested values.

As such, you should not use a class but rather an interface. Furthermore, as suggested in the other answer, you should annotate members that may be absent as optional.

You will need to provide the default values yourself.